# Is there a simpler way to read off *.jar or filesystem?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, spark-java

I've developed a simple app using Sparkjava. I'm using Intellij, and when I run my tests, or run the app locally, all my resources are files.

However, when I deploy, the whole thing runs as a jar file. As such, I need a way to read my resources off the filesystem or the jar, depending on how the app is launched. The following code gets the job done, but it looks clumsy:

```
String startedOffFile = new java.io.File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource()
        .getLocation()
        .getPath())
        .getName();
InputStream inputStream;
if(startedOffFile.endsWith(".jar")) {
    ClassLoader cl = PropertiesParser.class.getClassLoader();
    inputStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("myapp.dev.properties");
} else {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
}
```

Is there a cleaner/simpler way?

Comment: Why not always load the resources from the classpath (i.e. using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()), rather than using file IO? Whether the resources are in a directory that is in the classpath or in a jar that is in the classpath doesn't make a difference for your code.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Why not check if the files exist? If they do load the files, if not load from jar resources.

Comment: I agree with @PouriaP. You can choose if the properties from a jar or filesystem using -D parameters. `java -jar app.jar -DpropertyLocation=xxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Maven with IntelliJ, just put the configuration properties file inside the `src/main/resources` directory in the module. If you're not using Maven then put the properties file in the root of your source tree (outside any package - like: `src/myapp.dev.properties`).

After packaging/exporting of the JAR the file will be accessible with `new Object().getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myapp.dev.properties")` (the `new Object()...` is used, because in some cases/platforms the static ClassLoader is not defined).

The same classpath is used by the IntelliJ/Eclipse environment, which means there is no need for a special case for loading the files.

If you need to differentiate between development and production properties. You can use Maven profiles for build time packaging or you can load the properties with a variable using the -D switch.

Comment: Using maven to build specific Jars for specific environments isn't a good idea. The world has moved on long ago. Continuous deployment, DevOps, and Container deployment work best when you externalise your configuration and have your code react to it.

Comment: The question does not specify the type of the application. It could be a desktop one, don't forget this is stil a quite common type of application where DevOps, containers and new age deployment concepts are not present. The second thing to note is the actual problem, loading the same configuration while running tests in IntelliJ and as a standalone JAR file. Lastly, the answer clearly suggests a -D option to override the properties file.

Comment: DevOps works in all app types, including Desktops. Nothing new about continuous deployment. This question is about a web server. Building different Jars (Desktop or otherwise) using Maven isn't wrong, but can lead to issues. Building a single Jar for all deployments, including IntelliJ, is a better option, as it simplifies the codebase.

Comment: Including a default set of settings in jar files is still a quite common practice, because it let's you override them by classloader or by providing the configuration manually which satisfies all actual needs. It has been quite a common practice to use a "working directory", which is added to the classpath, for many years now. The working directory contains different resources and configurations, they get accessed exactly how I described above, which from the code point of view is better and more portable between Java platforms.

Comment: @domfarr I'm not saying you're wrong, but that I'm right too. If you want to continue to talk about the topic, just ping me privately, somehow. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have your `main` create this class to determine if your `java` executable has defined a config.location parameter or will look on the classpath.

eg. `java -Dconfig.location=/here/myapp.dev.properties -jar youapp.jar`

```
public class ApplicationProperties {
    public ApplicationProperties() throws IOException {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        String location = getProperty("config.location")
        if(location != null) {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(getProperty("config.location", ENV_PROPERTIES_PATH)));
        } else {
            properties.load(Classname.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myapp.dev.properties"));
        }
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```